# Get the Rad button that were clicked after Post Back

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm using telerik Grid which has a command button that adds new row/record or another command button that edits selected row/record.

Each grid is inside a twitter bootstrap tab content (Yes, I didn't use telerik tab). What is happening is that when one of buttons that I mentioned above clicked, I expect the tab that contains that button be active at page load.

So is there anyway to get that button so I can use it to activate the proper tab? (ID of that button is enough for me, I will do the rest with jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every control that posts back, in an ASP.NET web forms world, sets the `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` (if there is an argument) form values.  The `__EVENTTARGET` form variable has the client ID of the button, so that might be the optimal way.  If it's within the grid, I'm not sure, but the `__EVENTTARGET` may either be the button or grid ID.